# Scrollbar appering at the bottom of web page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I used animation plugin from http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/ . If i delete this (jQuery and CSS), then website content shows fine.

But with this jQuery and CSS, in view point appearing a bottom scroll bar. my testing website is : http://test.webegenius.es/

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: I don't see any bottom scroll bar in http://test.webegenius.es/ on firefox

Comment: Hi,,
This appear, when you scroll down smoothly. but when view point is in middle , then its disappear.

Comment: I see, it seems to disapear as "Ultimos Proyectos" appears so maybe you can look in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar is appearing because your animation is moving elements to the right, off the screen and then animating them back into view. This makes your page wider and the browser puts on a scroll bar to match the width.

If you modify one of the divs that contains this section to have a hidden overflow, the elements that are moved will be hidden when they overflow, so the page will remain the same size.

Do this on the main div with class container, that contains  the whole page. It is just after the closing of the div with class header_bg in the markup

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Oaw.,, Thanks...you save my day !!  :)